# Oscillator in Energy Basis Lowering and Raising Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

On page 205 of [Shankar's Intro to Quantum Mechanics](http://home.basu.ac.ir/~psu/Books/%5BRamamurti_Shankar%5D_Principles_of_Quantum_Mechanic(BookFi.org).pdf), equation 7.4.12 does not make sense to me. I understand why a|e> is an eigenvector and why e-1 is its Eigenvalue, but I don't understand how that translates to a|e> = C|e-1>. If someone could explain how they get that equation I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$| e-1 \rangle$ is *defined* to be the normalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $e-1$.  But just because a vector is an eigenvector doesn't mean it's necessarily normalized, so you need to include the $C$ to take into account the eigenvector's normalization.

Comment: Ok but how do they get that equation?

Comment: @GavinN. I thought you said "I understand why a|e> is an eigenvector and why e-1 is its Eigenvalue."

Comment: I do but Shankar originally solves for the eigenvalues of H hat, not of the operator a. How does he go from solving the eigenvalues of H^ to this equation?

Comment: @Gavin N. You're getting confused what $| e \rangle$ and $| e-1 \rangle$ are eigenvectors *of*.  They're eigenvectors of $\hat{H}$, *not* of $a$.  If $| e \rangle$ where an eigenvector of $a$, then $a |e \rangle$ would be proportional to $| e \rangle$, but it's not.  I think if you go back to Shankar and reread it bearing this in mind, it should make sense now.